# Click on Menu item in Appium Android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have to  click on Menu highlighted in Image using Appium driver I Tried Below codes 
for Place Order menu

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='5']/android.view.View[@index='0']").click(); and 
WebElement mobile = driver.scrollTo("Place Order");
                        System.out.println("scroll till Place Order in home slider menu");
                        mobile.click();


  driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Place Order").click();
```

but getting error

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 55.14 seconds

I have given wait time and there is no issue about wait time

[image]

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions on SO.Coming to your question the element doesnt have an id so no way it will be able to  find your element by an id - Place Order.

Comment: i used ByAccessibilityID not ByID or By.id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change  `driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Place Order").click();` to `driver.findElementByName("Place Order").click();` And try again. It should work.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro what do u mean? Just at the question above and i am giving him an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all  Gaurav i changed driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Place Order").click(); to driver.findElementByName("Place Order").click(); but it's not working

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution.

There was no resource id or content description available even after been setting up for menu items. Still not available in uiAutomatorViewer.

So i get the menu item by its xpath. like this:

```
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.CheckedTextView[@text='Home']").click();
```

the class for menu item was 'android.widget.CheckedTextView' so i add the Label of menu item which is 'Home'. So it works.
Hope it helps